# Web Scraping to Single String with Python

Tags: python, string, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the text of a web page and output it as a single string composed of each of the words that made up the sentences/paragraphs of the text. However I can't seem to concatenate the individual sentences/paragraphs. I thought maybe it was because of white space or line breaks, but attempting to remove those results in the same issue.

Could someone take a look at my code and explain what I'm doing wrong? (Explanations are super helpful so I can fully understand your correction.)

Here's my code:

```
import requests, re, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = ['http://t24.com.tr/haber/suriyelilere-vatandasliga-neden-karsi-cikiliyor,348652', 'http://t24.com.tr/haber/oteki-suriyeliler-turkiye-vatandasi-olursak-askere-gideriz-akpye-oy-verir-miyim-bilmiyorum,349206', 'http://t24.com.tr/haber/konyada-turklerle-suriyeliler-arasinda-kopege-niye-tekme-attin-kavgasi-3-olu-2-yarali,349208']


for url in urls:
    html = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

paragraphs = soup.findAll('p', {"class" : "p1"})
for p in paragraphs:
    text = p.text.replace(',', '').replace('"', '').replace('.', '').replace("'", "").replace('?', '').replace("\n", "").replace('\r', '')
    print(text)
```

My output currently looks like this:

```
Selin Girit                                                                                                             
Kendi ülkesinde savaştan kaçacak sınavsız okula girip askerlik yapmayacak 10 yıl sonra benden iyi yaşayacak #ÜlkemdeSuriyeliİstemiyorum                   
Cumhurbaşkanı Recep Tayyip Erdoğanın Türkiyede yaşayan Suriyeli mültecilere
```

When what I'd like is this:

```
Selin Girit Kendi ülkesinde savaştan kaçacak sınavsız okula girip askerlik yapmayacak 10 yıl sonra benden iyi yaşayacak #ÜlkemdeSuriyeliİstemiyorum Cumhurbaşkanı Recep Tayyip Erdoğanın Türkiyede yaşayan Suriyeli mültecilere
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: You are creating a new soup for each url in the first for loop before doing anything with each of the soups. So with your code you would only get the text from the last url in `urls`. First thing you should do is put the paragraph loop inside the url-loop.

`soup.findAll()` returns an iterator, `paragraphs`, with all p-tags at the page. You can before looping paragraphs create an empty string, `full_string`, and then add each paragraph to this empty string to get your desired result. As below.

```
for url in urls:
    html = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

    full_text = ''
    paragraphs = soup.findAll('p', {"class" : "p1"})
    for p in paragraphs:
        text = p.text.replace(',', '').replace('"', '').replace('.', '').replace("'", "").replace('?', '').replace("\n", "").replace('\r', '')
        full_text += text

    print text
```